# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while accessing v3/api-docs

Tags: swagger, openapi, nosuchmethoderror

I am using Open api 1.6.12, swagger ui 4.1.3 and swagger core 2.1.12
Here is the log:
`{"time": "2022-12-07 11:27:08,090","level": "ERROR","transactionId": "","source": "reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers:315","thread": "parallel-3","class": "reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers","message": "Scheduler worker in group main failed with an uncaught exception", "stack_trace":"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema.addProperty(java.lang.String, io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema)'    at org.springdoc.core.RequestBodyInfo.addProperties(RequestBodyInfo.java:91)    at org.springdoc.core.GenericParameterService.calculateRequestBodySchema(GenericParameterService.java:390)  at org.springdoc.core.GenericParameterService.calculateSchema(GenericParameterService.java:352) at org.springdoc.core.RequestBodyService.buildRequestBody(RequestBodyService.java:275)  at org.springdoc.core.RequestBodyService.calculateRequestBodyInfo(RequestBodyService.java:251)  at org.springdoc.core.AbstractRequestService.build(AbstractRequestService.java:313) at org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.calculatePath(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:471)    at org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.calculatePath(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:633)    at org.springdoc.webflux.api.OpenApiResource.lambda$calculatePath$5(OpenApiResource.java:210)   at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)    at org.springdoc.webflux.api.OpenApiResource.calculatePath(OpenApiResource.java:192)    at org.springdoc.webflux.api.OpenApiResource.lambda$getPaths$0(OpenApiResource.java:175)    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)    at org.springdoc.webflux.api.OpenApiResource.getPaths(OpenApiResource.java:167) at org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.getOpenApi(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:332)   at org.springdoc.webflux.api.OpenApiResource.openapiJson(OpenApiResource.java:136)  at org.springdoc.webflux.api.OpenApiWebfluxResource.openapiJson(OpenApiWebfluxResource.java:117)    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.lambda$invoke$0(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:144)   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125)  at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:251)   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:336) at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:89)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139)    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.request(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:75)   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onSubscribe(MonoZip.java:325)    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onSubscribe(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:68)   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)  at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:128)   at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203) at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onComplete(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:103)   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:181)  at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:120)   at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)  at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:282)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863)   at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:89)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:169)   at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.request(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:75)   at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2194)    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2068)    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onSubscribe(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:68)   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)  at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:451)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:219)  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87)  at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)   at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:89)    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398) at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.request(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:75)   at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2194)    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2068)    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onSubscribe(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:68)   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:150)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:196)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:268) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:148)  at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime.subscribeOrReturn(MonoCacheTime.java:151)   at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118)   at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:89)    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398) at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.request(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:75)   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:110) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:87)   at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onSubscribe(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:68)   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCurrentContext.subscribe(MonoCurrentContext.java:36)  at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)   at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:89)    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398) at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.request(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:75)   at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2194)    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2068)    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onSubscribe(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:68)   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:85)   at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onComplete(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:103)   at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:181)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:196)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:268) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:148)  at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime.subscribeOrReturn(MonoCacheTime.java:151)   at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118)   at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:89)    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398) at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.request(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:75)   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:110) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:87)   at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onSubscribe(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:68)   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCurrentContext.subscribe(MonoCurrentContext.java:36)  at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:299) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:299) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:148)  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113)   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:101)   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:282)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863)   at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:89)    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113)   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:854)  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113)   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmitScalar(FluxFlatMap.java:488)   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:421)  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:272) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:230)  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87)  at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:451)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:219)  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87)  at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)  at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166)   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:940)  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:85)   at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2400) at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2194)    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2068)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)  at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:102) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166)   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:846) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:608)   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:588)   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:465)  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:277) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:294) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:230)  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87)  at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)  at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:109)   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166)   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:269) at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1817)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.signalCached(MonoCacheTime.java:337)  at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.onNext(MonoCacheTime.java:354)    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)   at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:89)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:89)    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(MonoPublishOn.java:181) at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ReactorSleuth.lambda$null$6(ReactorSleuth.java:324)  at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)", "trace": "", "span": "", "type": "services-medication-applog"}`

I can see there is no addProperty in Schema class. How can I resolve this?